# Como fazer ao clicar no ok do alert, só então ir para outra pagina?

Tags: ionic, alert, visual-studio-code

Bom galera, estou aprendendo ionic agora na faculdade, e gostaria de saber se é possível, em um alert, fazer com que somente após o usuário clicar em 'ok', no meu caso 'alterar', ele ir para uma determinada página? Agradeço a atenção.

Código:

```
presentConfirm() {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Alteração',
  message: 'Você realmente deseja alterar?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Não',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Clicou no Cancelar');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Sim',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Clicou no Alterar');
      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funcionou pra min deste modo

```
presentConfirm() {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Alteração',
  message: 'Você realmente deseja alterar?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Não',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Clicou no Cancelar');

      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Sim',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Clicou no Alterar');
        this.navCtrl.push(NovaPage);
      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
}
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo, funcionou!